# Laravel/Lumen - How to trigger a job process from a website?

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen

I'm using Lumen queues. To start the jobs being processed, the docs indicate to run the queue listener **from the command line** like so:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

I'd like to trigger my queue jobs processes directly **from my code**. How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any artisan command you like directly from your code:

```php
Artisan::call('queue:listen');
```

For information, [read the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code).